# Change dimensions of array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a 3D array:

```
my.array <- array(1:120, dim=c(3,4,10))

dim(my.array)
[1]  3  4 10
```

3,4 are width,height of matrix and 10 number of matrices. To be in accordance with Keras input (number of matrices first), I want to change the order of dimensions as:

```
dim(my.array)
[1]  10  3  4
```

The first matrix is:

```
my.array[,,1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

If I do `dim(my.array) <- c(10, 3, 4)`. My first matrix will:

```
my.array[1,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   31   61   91
[2,]   11   41   71  101
[3,]   21   51   81  111
```

So it is not correct because it changes the order of values. The first matrix after the modification must be:

```
my.array[1,,]
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    1    4    7   10
    [2,]    2    5    8   11
    [3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Comment: Can you just try `dim(my.array) <- c(10, 3, 4)`  It is better to show the expected output

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: `aperm(my.array, c(3, 1, 2))` works. I got there because this seemed like an analogue of transposition, and `aperm` is linked from `?t`.

Comment: We can use `aperm(my.array, c(3, 2, 1))`